# Left join operation runs forever

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I have to DataFrames that I want to join applying Left joining.

df1 =

```
+----------+---------------+
|product_PK| rec_product_PK|
+----------+---------------+
|       560|            630|
|       710|            240|
|       610|            240|
```

df2 =

```
+----------+---------------+-----+
|product_PK| rec_product_PK| rank|
+----------+---------------+-----+
|       560|            610|    1|
|       560|            240|    1|
|       610|            240|    0|
```

The problem is that `df1` contains only 500 rows, while `df2` contains 600.000.000 rows and 24 partitions. My Left joining takes a while to execute. I am waiting for 5 hours and it is not finished.

```
val result = df1.join(df2,Seq("product_PK","rec_product_PK"),"left")
```

The result should contain 500 rows. I execute the code from spark-shell using the following parameters:

```
spark-shell -driver-memory 10G --driver-cores 4 --executor-memory 10G --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 4
```

How can I speed up the process?

**UPDATE:**

The output of `df2.explain(true)`:

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Repartition 5000, true
+- Project [product_PK#15L AS product_PK#195L, product_PK#189L AS reco_product_PK#196L, col2#190 AS rank#197]
   +- Project [product_PK#15L, array_elem#184.product_PK AS product_PK#189L, array_elem#184.col2 AS col2#190]
      +- Project [product_PK#15L, products#16, array_elem#184]
         +- Generate explode(products#16), true, false, [array_elem#184]
            +- Relation[product_PK#15L,products#16] parquet

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
product_PK: bigint, rec_product_PK: bigint, rank: int
Repartition 5000, true
+- Project [product_PK#15L AS product_PK#195L, product_PK#189L AS reco_product_PK#196L, col2#190 AS rank_product_family#197]
   +- Project [product_PK#15L, array_elem#184.product_PK AS product_PK#189L, array_elem#184.col2 AS col2#190]
      +- Project [product_PK#15L, products#16, array_elem#184]
         +- Generate explode(products#16), true, false, [array_elem#184]
            +- Relation[product_PK#15L,products#16] parquet

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Repartition 5000, true
+- Project [product_PK#15L, array_elem#184.product_PK AS rec_product_PK#196L, array_elem#184.col2 AS rank#197]
   +- Generate explode(products#16), true, false, [array_elem#184]
      +- Relation[product_PK#15L,products#16] parquet

== Physical Plan ==
Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(5000)
+- *Project [product_PK#15L, array_elem#184.product_PK AS rec_PK#196L, array_elem#184.col2 AS rank#197]
   +- Generate explode(products#16), true, false, [array_elem#184]
      +- *FileScan parquet [product_PK#15L,products#16] Batched: false, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://data/result/2017-11-27/..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<product_PK:bigint,products:array<struct<product_PK:bigint,col2:int>>>
```

Comment: @RaphaelRoth: I don't think that `600.000.000` is such a huge number of rows. Therefore I cannot understand why filtering or joining takes such a long time (I mean `count()` or `show()` after these operations).

Comment: maybe your data is still too large given you have only 24 partitions. With your configuration, you your maximum task size is limited to ~ 0.5*10/4=1.25 GB. You should try to increase the number of partitions for df2 (using e.g. `df2.repartition(1000)`). Or try to set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to something like 5000

Comment: @RaphaelRoth: So, if I understood correctly, I should firstly apply `df2.repartition(1000)).` and then I should do filtering. Finally I should do `count()` and then `join`. Right?

Comment: I would not do the filtering, just the broadcast-join (but I assume spark is doing a broadcast-join anyway, you should check the physical plan to see what spark is doing). In general I would try to increase parallelism, and also keep an eye on the Spark UI to check which stage is causing problems

Comment: @RaphaelRoth: How to increase parallelism? Would you increase `spark.sql.autoBroadCastJoinThreshold` to more Mb?

Comment: no I would not increase `spark.sql.autoBroadCastJoinThreshold` as you can simply force a broadcast-join using the bordcast-hint as mentioned in the answers. I would just try to increase the number of partitions of df2

Comment: @RaphaelRoth: Ok, I see. I am now testing 1000 partitions. If it takes too long time again, I will try `df2.repartition(2000)` and so on.

Comment: note that `explode` can be extremly slow in spark 2.x (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21657?attachmentOrder=desc), you should post your entire code. Maybe it's not the join but the explode which is causing problems!

Comment: @RaphaelRoth: Please check this question that I posted some days ago (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48480647/how-to-transform-dataframe-before-joining-operation). I posted the example and code. I use the solution proposed there.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth: I've just checked `count()` right after `explode` (before `join`). It took some 3 minutes. So, I assume that the problem is with `join`, because when I put `count` after `join` the process gets stuck (with any repartitioning).

Comment: Note that count does NOT fully evaluate the dataframe, you need to do df.rdd.count

Answer (score 5):

You should probably use a different type of join. By default the join you are making assumes both dataframes are large and therefore a lot of shuffling is done (Generally each row would be hashed, the data would be shuffled based on the hashing, then a per executor joining would be done). You can see this by typing using explain on the result to see the execution plan.

Instead consider using the broadcast hint:

```
val result = df2.join(broadcast(df1),Seq("product_PK","rec_product_PK"),"right")
```

note that I flipped the join order so the broadcast would appear in the join parameters. The broadcast function is part of org.apache.spark.sql.functions

This would do a broadcast join instead, df1 would be copied to all executors and the joining would be done locally avoiding the need to shuffle the large df2.

Comment: Could you please show how to use `explain`? Also, could you please put some reference to what you explained in the first paragraph? It's an interesting fact that I would like to read more about.

Comment: I increased the number of executors to 6 (in my case this is the maximum) and use `broadcast` as you explained. It seems to get stuck again. Waiting. I use `result.show()` to push Spark to execute joining.

Comment: why did you changed the join order? You can also write `broadcast(df1).join(df2),Seq("product_PK","rec_product_PK"),"left")`

Comment: Unless auto broadcast threshold is very low there is no difference compared to the code, that OP already has.

Comment: @user8371915 auto broadcast doesn't always work. Specifically if the dataframe is created from an external source such as file and it has not been added to hive metastore.

Answer (score 1):

Given the exceptionally small size of your `df1`, it might be worth considering to first `collect` it into a list, and filter the large `df2` with the list down to a comparably small dataframe, which is then used for a `left` join with `df1`:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  (560L, 630L),
  (710L, 240L),
  (610L, 240L)
).toDF("product_PK", "rec_product_PK")

val df2 = Seq(
  (560L, 610L, 1),
  (560L, 240L, 1),
  (610L, 240L, 0)
).toDF("product_PK", "rec_product_PK", "rank")

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val pkList = df1.collect.map{
  case Row(pk1: Long, pk2: Long) => (pk1, pk2)
}.toList
// pkList: List[(Long, Long)] = List((560,630), (710,240), (610,240))

def inPkList(pkList: List[(Long, Long)]) = udf(
  (pk1: Long, pk2: Long) => pkList.contains( (pk1, pk2) )
)

val df2Filtered = df2.where( inPkList(pkList)($"product_PK", $"rec_product_PK") )
// +----------+--------------+----+
// |product_PK|rec_product_PK|rank|
// +----------+--------------+----+
// |       610|           240|   0|
// +----------+--------------+----+

df1.join(df2Filtered, Seq("product_PK", "rec_product_PK"), "left_outer")
// +----------+--------------+----+
// |product_PK|rec_product_PK|rank|
// +----------+--------------+----+
// |       560|           630|null|
// |       710|           240|null|
// |       610|           240|   0|
// +----------+--------------+----+
```

Comment: I get this error when creating `pkList`: `scala.MatchError: [67207790,67210680] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)`

Comment: If I run `df2Filtered.count()` after the line `val df2Filtered = df2.where( inPkList(pkList)($"product_PK", $"rec_product_PK") )`, then it takes a while again. I don't know if it even will finish.

Comment: The `MatchError` is probably caused by the `Int` type in my example not matching your actual PK column type.  I've updated the answer to use `Long`.

Comment: Yes, I changed the type to Long. But again the process gets stuck, taking a while to finish. I think that 600.000.000 should not be such a great amount of data for Spark. I do not understand why this operation cannot be executed. Maybe I should not run `count` and I should just directly save `result` in S3 using `write`?

Comment: The long wait for count might imply that `df2Filtered` is still relatively big compared with `df1` (i.e. there are many rows in `df2` with PKs matching the PK list), in which case it would make sense to apply `broadcast` to `df1` for the final join.

Comment: Doesn't `count` imply that filtering is actually executed, because Spark is lazy? When I run `val df2Filtered = df2.where( inPkList(pkList)($"product_PK", $"rec_product_PK") )`, it gets executed in few seconds, but it's lazy execution.

Comment: This looks completely pointless. You filter out records which would be efficiently removed in OP code, but replace constant time lookups with _O(m)_ where m= 500 linear search. Why in Earth?

Comment: Point well taken, although I see 500-element in-memory search a trivial cost.  I, too, would've first tried `join` with `broadcast` before the suggested `collect` approach.  I suppose the main question is whether Spark can more optimally perform filtering a single dataframe than joining the dataframe with another one.